# Billing users for viewing maps?

Tags: google-maps, bing-maps, yahoo-maps

Both Google and Yahoo allow the commercial use of their Maps API so long as users may view the maps for free. Does any provider allow customization of their maps and charging users to view it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I imagine you could contact Rand McNally or other conventional mapping companies, see about licensing their products - and their licensing terms might include the ability to charge for the use of the maps on the developers -> end users side of things.